# Add more functions in Gedit

Tags: gedit

I'm trying out Ubuntu for the first time so I'm a very new but I've done a bit of searching and I want to get something pretty similar to Notepad++

Gedit so far seems to be the pretty similar except I like a feature in N++ where I can add more function names to a list so it knows to colour them a certain way. For example in my prepared statements (PHP) I use things such as `prepare` or `execute` but Gedit doesn't recognize these and just leaves them white.

I'm sure there must be a file somewhere which contains a list of all known function names and I'd imagine you can edit it to add more, but I have no idea on where to start looking? I can't find a plugin for it either so I guess this is the only way.

Either that or I install Wine and use that to run N++ but a tutorial I found for that tells me to start typing in all sorts of things to install it and I have no idea where I being typing them ha. Plus it kinda defeats the point of me having Ubuntu if I'm just gonna revert to a Windows emulator all the time :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gedit has a wide range of features, from syntax highlighting to plugins.

See :

http://grigio.org/pimp_my_gedit_was_textmate_linux

http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins

http://www.micahcarrick.com/gedit-html-editor.html

Is there some function you want not covered in one of those links (I am not familiar with Notepad ++ ) ?

There are other editors with a number of features (vim / gvim / cream / emacs), vim is my favorite. Cream is in the ubuntu repositories and is cross platform

http://cream.sourceforge.net/

Cream features / screenshots - http://cream.sourceforge.net/features.html

If all else fails, you can run notebook ++ in wine

http://portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable

notepadpp portable would also be cross platform.

Answer (score 2):

The highlighting comes from "gtksourceview" and to edit the system PHP config file:

```
sudo -e  /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/php.lang
```

You might be able to [search for gtksourceview themes](http://live.gnome.org/GtkSourceView/StyleSchemes) for PHP somewhere on the Net.
You might also like the [symbol browser plugin](http://www.micahcarrick.com/gedit-symbol-browser-plugin.html). Are you able to accomplish every goal with one text editor? There are many great text editors to try maybe if you like...

- vim (`sudo apt-get install vim`)
- gvim (`sudo apt-get install gvim`)
- [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit/downloads)
- [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/uex.html) (30-day trial)
- [...] It just goes on and on and on... :)

Gvim is sort-of like "the gui version of vim."
Komodo Edit is free and designed for what you are doing (and more).
UltraEdit is of course commercial but I know no other software that can select text vertically.

Comment: You'll be surprised how many editors support column selection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802616/how-to-select-columns-in-editors-and-ides-notepad-kate-vim-netbeans